# Exterior light fixture: White wire hot, black wire not,

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I have an outdoor flood light fixture that stopped working. I don’t use it often so it could have stopped working at any time.

I changed the bulbs and that didn’t work, so I got a new fixture.
I took down the old fixture, then checked the wires (*one black, one white, no ground was attached*) with a proximity  volt detector. It showed there was voltage in the white wire and none in the black wire.

I tried hooking up the new fixture with black on black and white on white and the light would not work. I tried black on white and white on black and still the light did not work although the voltage detector still showed a charge.

There are several lights on the same circuit with two way switches and a couple out keys. I checked the outlets with a receptacle tester and they show as being normal. The switches seem to be wired correctly.

I have not pulled down the interior light fixtures to examine them yet.

Any clues as to what is going on?

Comment: The "hot" wire going to this outside light comes from a wall switch, right? This means it is a switched hot, that is, the wire is hot only when the switch is on. Sometimes a white wire is used for the switched hot. If this is the case, then it would be correct to connect this white wire to a black lead wire of the fixture. You would tell if this white wire is the switched hot from the switch by holding your noncontact voltage detector near or on the white wire  and having someone flip the switch on and off.

Comment: Voltage detectors aren't great ways to check for line-level power. There can often be stray voltage in house wiring. Use a multimeter and look for ~120 AC volts.

Comment: You should edit your post to include a photo of the fixture box so we can see what wires are there. In the US all neutrals are white, but not all whites are neutrals. With older wiring sometimes white and black wires are properly connected. In this fixture box and others you may examine do not assume that a connection of a white wire to a black is a wrong connection.

Comment: Where is this, what country?

Comment: I am wondering since it appeared to be improperly wired if the neutral was switched. I had an entire house I purchased in Ohio wired backward hot on white , neutral with switches on the black. It was a shocking experience for me.

Comment: This is in the US (Ohio) the wire stays hot either way I throw the switch, which is also odd